# Interface builder not showing anything

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I have been using IB for a while now and have created several projects. Now for some reason the inspector is always displaying (Empty Selection) no matter what I have selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try double-clicking an element in the Document window. Sometimes I have had to double-click an item for the details to be shown in the Inspector.